# What does "array.length + 1" mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I know how to use Javascript for loops to cycle through arrays. But I still don't fully understand what the array.length + 1 is doing, specifically the +1 part.

When using a for loop I know it goes like this

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){...}
```

But I'm also seeing this

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++){...}
```

I previously thought that array.length + 1 was the same thing as letting i = 1 but my code hasn't worked when doing that, for instance

```
for(let i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
```

is not the same thing as the for loop above. Can someone explain why?

Comment: `array.length + 1` just means "one more than the length of the array". Because it takes the length of the array and adds one to it. It doesn't change what the initial value of `i` is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: in fact it has the opposite effect of starting `i` as 1 because it will run one iteration longer rather than one less.

Comment: What is more important is what are you doing with that `i`? As index into "array" you should stop before your reach "length"

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){...}
```

loops from indicies 0 to `array.length - 1`. For example, with an array with 3 items, this iterates over `i`s of 0, 1, and 2.

This

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++){...}
```

is strange. It loops from indicies 0 to `array.length`. For example, with an array with 3 items, this iterates over `i`s of 0, 1, 2, and 3. This means that if something inside the loop references `array[i]`, that value will be `undefined` on the final iteration.

Most of the time, seeing something like that would make me think someone made a typo or logic error - though I wouldn't be surprised to see a few algorithms that used something like it.

This

```
for(let i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
```

iterates from indicies 1 to `array.length - 1`. For example, with an array with 3 items, this iterates over `i`s of 1, and 2.

There will be one less iteration than elements in the array. This means that, if the loop body always references `array[i]`, and not `array[i - 1]`, then the first element in the array will always be skipped over.

This is much less common than starting at 0, but could be seen, especially when the logic requires comparing certain adjacent elements against each other (for example, `array[0]` to `array[1]`, and `array[1]` to `array[2]`, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.length + 1
```

simply put is just the number of elements in the array and add 1.

An array with `n` elements has a length of n , so your loop will run `n - i` times when using `array.length`. If `let i =0` , then your loop will run `n` times. If `i = 1` , then your loop will run `n-1` times if using `array.length`. So you will be missing 1 iteration of your loop.

If you need to use `i=1` to start your iterations, you should use `array.length +1` to get the equivalent number of iterations.

```
for(let i =0;i<array.length;i++){} // n iterations
```

is the same number of iterations as

```
for(let i= 1;i<array.length +1;i++){}  // n iterations
```

```
for(let i=1;i<array.length;i++){}  // n-1 iterations
```

will always be 1 less iteration.

And remember, Array indexing uses a `0-based` counter, so array[0] is the first element of every array.